# How to get tag content with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-replace

My string `<a href="/?an=mb_artist&uid=40574" target="_blank">Maroon 5</a> - <a href="/?an=mb_track&uid=151311">One More Night</a>`

Try to get content of a tags with regexp `/<a.*>(.*)<\/a>/ig` , but get only "One More Night", how to get "Maroon 5" and "One More Night"  ?

Comment: It might help to show us the code you are running - the problem is as likely to be the way you are retrieving the results as it is with the expression itself.

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Andre you can, but it's not adviced to do it with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a question-mark after the `*`. Without an question-mark the regular expressions tries to match as many as characters as possible (greedy mode). With the question-mark as little as possible.

```
/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ig
```

Without:

```
    /<a.*>(.*)<\/a>/ig
//   ^^^^^ this part matches: <a href="/?an=mb_artist&uid=40574" target="_blank">Maroon 5</a> - <a href="/?an=mb_track&uid=151311">
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/hX1aD1/2

Update:

```
var myRe = /<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ig;
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null)
{
  var content = myArray[1];
  // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you have got much more beautifull means of working with markup DOM.

For example jQuery library...

See my fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3kfcp156/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').each(function(item,idx) {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
     });
```

Comment: thanks, but I want with regexp, in your example want to add:

var a = '<a href="/?an=mb_artist&uid=40574" target="_blank">Maroon 5</a> - <a href="/?an=mb_track&uid=151311">One More Night</a>';
$(a).filter("a").each(function(item,idx) {
            alert($(this).text());
        });

Comment: why? you can convert html to string and parse it